# Not getting expected output while converting JPEG to TIFF image C# using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Net library

Tags: c#, tiff, libtiff.net

We are not getting expected output after converting JPEG file to TIFF using below property values.I am using [BitMiracle LibTiff.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET/) library for this.

Output was visible 50% of actual image with blur lines.

We are below properties for converting jpeg to tiff image.Please suggest if anything wrong on this properties and help to improve it.

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream))
   {
     using (Tiff tif = Tiff.Open(tiffOutImgPath, "w"))
       {
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.SUBFILETYPE, 0);      
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, bmp.Width);
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, bmp.Height);
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, 8);
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.JPEG);
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISBLACK);

         tif.SetField(TiffTag.STRIPOFFSETS, BitConverter.ToInt32(stripOffset, 0));
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.ORIENTATION, Orientation.TOPLEFT);
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);

         tif.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, BitConverter.ToInt32(rowStripArr, 0));
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.STRIPBYTECOUNTS, BitConverter.ToInt32(stripByCount, 0));                     
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION, dpiVal);
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION, dpiVal);
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.RESOLUTIONUNIT, ResUnit.INCH);
         tif.SetField(TiffTag.PLANARCONFIG, PlanarConfig.CONTIG);
      }
  }
```

Please help me on the above property values, anything missing or require to change for getting expected output.

Comment: Shouldn't `SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISBLACK)` be `SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.RGB)` for JPEG images? And also `SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 3)`?

Comment: tried with same,some how output changed. but still need better solution,output of the image was cropped and image size also increased. Image size should be reduced. please give some better solution for this. thanks